# Split a SAM file in Awk keeping N number of lines as header

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, samtools, bam

I have a very big Sequence Alignment Map (SAM) file as depicted below

```
 @X   YYYYYY ZZZZZ\
 @X   ssssss ddddd\
 @X   CCCCCC LLLLL
 
> FFFFFF    117 ch1 16448   0   *   =   16448   0   TCTTGCACTGATCTGATGGACAGCATTGATGACATAACACGGAGACTGTTGCTAAAAACATCCGATAAAACTCGTGCTCAGACACCAAATACTCAAGAAG    JJFEJDDDBDJJJHJDDDHDJJEFJDJJCDFDJEJCEHHFDDDJDJEHEEJFJJJHDIFJJJJJDJDDHHJCDDJJFJFJEJFEDJJJDH##########    MC:Z:55S22M23S  RG:Z:Sample_POP1    AS:i:0  XS:i:0
> FFFFFF    117 ch6 16448   0   *   =   16448   0   TCTTGCACTGATCTGATGGACAGCATTGATGACATAACACGGAGACTGTTGCTAAAAACATCCGATAAAACTCGTGCTCAGACACCAAATACTCAAGAAG    JJFEJDDDBDJJJHJDDDHDJJEFJDJJCDFDJEJCEHHFDDDJDJEHEEJFJJJHDIFJJJJJDJDDHHJCDDJJFJFJEJFEDJJJDH##########    MC:Z:55S22M23S  RG:Z:Sample_POP1    AS:i:0  XS:i:0
> FFFFFF    117 ch2 16448   0   *   =   16448   0   TCTTGCACTGATCTGATGGACAGCATTGATGACATAACACGGAGACTGTTGCTAAAAACATCCGATAAAACTCGTGCTCAGACACCAAATACTCAAGAAG    JJFEJDDDBDJJJHJDDDHDJJEFJDJJCDFDJEJCEHHFDDDJDJEHEEJFJJJHDIFJJJJJDJDDHHJCDDJJFJFJEJFEDJJJDH##########    MC:Z:55S22M23S  RG:Z:Sample_POP1    AS:i:0  XS:i:0
> FFFFFF    117 ch5 16448   0   *   =   16448   0   TCTTGCACTGATCTGATGGACAGCATTGATGACATAACACGGAGACTGTTGCTAAAAACATCCGATAAAACTCGTGCTCAGACACCAAATACTCAAGAAG    JJFEJDDDBDJJJHJDDDHDJJEFJDJJCDFDJEJCEHHFDDDJDJEHEEJFJJJHDIFJJJJJDJDDHHJCDDJJFJFJEJFEDJJJDH##########    MC:Z:55S22M23S  RG:Z:Sample_POP1    AS:i:0  XS:i:0
> FFFFFF    117 ch1 16448   0   *   =   16448   0   TCTTGCACTGATCTGATGGACAGCATTGATGACATAACACGGAGACTGTTGCTAAAAACATCCGATAAAACTCGTGCTCAGACACCAAATACTCAAGAAG    JJFEJDDDBDJJJHJDDDHDJJEFJDJJCDFDJEJCEHHFDDDJDJEHEEJFJJJHDIFJJJJJDJDDHHJCDDJJFJFJEJFEDJJJDH##########    MC:Z:55S22M23S  RG:Z:Sample_POP1    AS:i:0  XS:i:0
```

I want to split the file based on column 3 so I can do `awk '{print > $3}' file.txt` which is working fine. Now I want to keep the lines

```
 @X   YYYYYY ZZZZZ\
 @X   ssssss ddddd\
 @X   CCCCCC LLLLL
```

as header on top of all the splitted files, how can I do that?

I tried this:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^@/ {print > $3}'  file.txt
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't want to use [samtools](http://www.htslib.org/)? E.g. `samtools view -h file.sam chr1 > chr1.sam` should provide the header lines and chr1 entries.

Comment: Yes that can also be used.

Comment: When you say `$3` in your question - do you mean the actual `$3` of `117` or did you really mean `$4` which contains those `ch<N>` strings?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. For common bioinformatics tasks, use open-source tools that are specifically designed for these tasks, are well-tested, widely used, and handle edge cases. Here, use [`samtools`](https://github.com/samtools/samtools), which can be easily installed with [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html), see the comment from *jared_mamrot*. Also, see: [How To Split A Bam File By Chromosome](https://www.biostars.org/p/46327/) and [split sorted bam file chromosome wise](https://www.biostars.org/p/405004/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep track of whether the file is one you have seen before, and if not, write the header before you write to it for the first time.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^@/ { header = header $0 ORS; next }
   !seen[$3]++ { printf "%s", header >$3 }
   { print > $3 }' file.txt
```

The internal variable `ORS` usually contains a newline but it's customary to use the variable so that you only need to change the string in one place if you want to use a different output record separator.

This can run out of file handles if you have more than a couple of dozen distinct values in `$3` but if your script otherwise works, I guess that's not a problem in your case.

(The brute-force fix is to close and reopen the file after each write, which makes the script much slower. A better fix if you have the memory is to collect all the results into RAM and only write when you have read all the data. A more sophisticated approach would keep a buffer of, say, 20 open file handles, and close the least recently used when you need to write to a file which isn't among them.)